# Consuming messages from Topic using Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-jms, consumer

I wonder what is the correct way to subscribe to a **Topic** using Spring.

I tried with a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, using a non-durable subscription, but it fails most of the time. There is an open bug ([SPR-7833](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7883?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)) that seems to point out it will not work for non-durable topic subscriptions.

Is there any alternative to the DMLC that supports auto-reconnection in case of failure?

By the way, I'm creating the DMLC programmatically, connecting to an embedded ActiveMQ 5.5.1 broker using the Failover Transport for automatic reconnection. Consuming messages from Queues work as expected even in the most bizarre scenarios, but no luck with Topics.